# Ngrok "client failed to establish a connection to the local address" Error

Tags: ngrok

Encountered ngrok error:

> client failed to establish a connection to the local address.

I'm running a local server in another terminal on the same port (8081). I've also used postman to confirm the server is running properly on my local machine.

What else would be causing this error?

I have an early 2015 Macbook Pro 13 inch running Sierra.

Comment: What is the ngrok command you are running? And where are you seeing that error message?

Answer (score 1):

While I was working on a Rails app I wanted to run it on **ngrok** but I got below error

`The connection to http://xxxxxx.ngrok.io was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address localhost:3000.`

It seems like ngrok works fine but my local server is not. Which is true since I forgot to run my rails app first by run `$ rails s`. By doing so I was able to get ngrok tunneing works fine.

Make sure your local server run first. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If `localhost` is missing from your `/etc/hosts`; ngrok may fail to resolve it.

Try to explicitly point to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`:

```sh
ngrok http 127.0.0.1:8080
```